# Access control checks Safari on S3 Direct upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Safari 10.1.2

I have an issue when trying to upload PDF files to S3 using a signed request using the Node aws-sdk. This happens intermittently and a google search is saying it's a CORS issue, but it works well 90% of the time! Pulling my hear out right now!

I did notice on Firefox this issue was happening if files are over 500Kb. I fixed that but am still getting this issue on Safari.

**Client**:

```
    // https://gist.github.com/guumaster/9f18204aca2bd6c71a24
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: signedRequest,
        // Content type must much with the parameter you signed your URL with
        contentType: file.type,
        // this flag is important, if not set, it will try to send data as a form
        processData: false,
        // the actual file is sent raw
        data: file,
        success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            addToSupportingDocsURLDO(annexureFilename, reference, url, callback);
        },
        error: function (err, textStatus, request) {
            _errorCallback('Could not upload file: ' + file.name + ' Please decrease the size of your file or try again later.');
            // TODO: send support@judgeit.com.au email with error
        }
    });
```

**Error**:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sofassets.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/597725898b90e600118f9c9d/599eb7843301240011281ecb/Annexure-D.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEYID&Content-Type=application%2Fpdf&Expires=1503574043&Signature=SIGNATURE&x-amz-acl=public-read due to access control checks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't sort this out or someone lands here like I did, we had the same problem and I still can't believe this was the problem but... changing our button from `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"` solved it. Apparently Apple decided that a submit button shouldn't be submitting data...